# Spring Data: multiple IN's inside a query

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have the following method inside my spring jpa data interface:

```
List<TransactRepViewModel> findByClientIdInAndClDateBetween(List<String> clientIdList, Date startDate, Date endDate)
```

The problem is that I get this error due to my clientIdList having about 5000-20000 String objects inside:

```
ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000
```

Is there a way to use multiple IN's inside a spring-data query and split up my list to avoid the error?

**Update**:

Ths is how I get my client object list:

```
List<ClieTabModel> clieTabModelList = clieTabModelRepository.findByCompanyId(companyViewModel.getId());
```

This is how I get the  list of client Id's:

```
List<String> clientIdList = new ArrayList <>();
            for (ClieTabModel clieTabModel : clieTabModelList) {
                clientIdList.add(clieTabModel.getClientId());
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure that passing 5000-20000 parameters in every query is a good decision? It's probably better to use sub-select/join in this case...

Comment: How many elements in the list ?

Comment: @javaguy a minimum of 5000.

Comment: @dmitrievanthony you may be right. How would that query look like? I am kind of new with hql.

Comment: @Deniss M. it depends on your case, I'm not clearly understand it. Where are you get list of clients ids? Is it possible to use `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @dmitrievanthony I have updated my original post with additional information. Please let me know if that is sufficient.

Comment: This limit is present in DBMS (Oracle and Sql Server too), write a subquery and resolve it

Comment: @JoeTaras I don't think it is a good idea to use IN for such a huge amount of objects... I may be wrong though.

Comment: @DenissM. Yes, I only write this limit is present on DBMS, so Spring Data must agreed this limit. Personally, I write a query with subquery to get this information.

Comment: @JoeTaras how would that sub query look like. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.id in :clientIds and :startDate=? and endDate= :endDate")
List<TransactRepViewModel> findByClientIdInAndClDateBetween(Set<String> clientIds, Date startDate, Date endDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see your ER model should look like this:
`Transact >--- Client >--- Company`.

So, in this case you can write follow query:

`List<TransactRepViewModel> findByClientCompanyIdAndClDateBetween(String companyId, Date startDate, Date endDate)`

Comment: That's what the code has now and when we get a list of 8000 clients, the application is making 8000 queries to the db. I don't think that is the way to go...

Comment: It's the other topic. To avoid multiple queries in JPA you can use `FETCH JOIN` or `@EntityGraph` for instance.